# Importing YAML in jsonnet

Tags: jsonnet

Is there a way how I can import a `.yaml` file in jsonnet?

I have found that jsonnet supports importing `.json` and also has a native `importstr()` function but looks like no support for `.yaml`?

I would like to do:

```
local foo = import "foo.yaml";
local bar = foo.bar;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at the moment (May/2018), there's an open issue for it at https://github.com/google/jsonnet/issues/460, *if* you're working with Kubernetes manifests (importing + massaging w/jsonnet) you could use https://github.com/ksonnet/kubecfg which contains a superset of jsonnet, including `std.parseYaml()`.

> **Update(2018-05-23): added `ksonnet` example**

Using `ksonnet`'s embedded `parseYaml`, at app folder:

```
$ cat assets/foo.yaml 
foo: value1
bar: value2

$ cat components/cm.jsonnet 
local env = std.extVar("__ksonnet/environments");
local params = std.extVar("__ksonnet/params").components.cm;
local k = import "k.libsonnet";
local configMap = k.core.v1.configMap;

local parseYaml = std.native("parseYaml");

configMap.new(params.name, params.data) {
  data+: parseYaml(importstr "../assets/foo.yaml")[0] {
    foo: "my own value",
  },
}

$ ks show default
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  bar: value2
  foo: my own value
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
```

Comment: I am using ksonnet and its not there - yet.

Comment: I think in `ksonnet` it is not `std.parseYaml`, but something like `local kubecfg = import "kubecfg.libsonnet"; kubecfg.parseYaml(yaml_string)`.

Comment: as `ksonnet` has common roots with `kubecfg` it's as @sbarzowski said (tho I had to directly use it via std.native()),  I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: ksonnet is no longer maintained and GH repos will be archived: https://blogs.vmware.com/cloudnative/2019/02/05/welcoming-heptio-open-source-projects-to-vmware/